# How to have two type of users with different logins using Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two type of Users Artist and Customer. so far I have this
in models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    Email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'Email'
    objects = MyUserManager()


class Customers(models.Model):
    User = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CustomerID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Artists(models.Model):
    User = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ArtistID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

I use Email as authentication, and it is good until an Artist wants to be Customer too.
and he/she can't have two accounts one as Customer and another as Artist with the same Email.

here my questions:

1. Is this way of implementation correct? if not, how to do that?
2. what is the best way to have a user be Artist and Customer at the same time? Is this have security issues?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that it's usually a bad idea to derive subclasses from Users.

Instead, use a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) and add flags for the various roles (and yes, I'm deriving from `AbstractUser` on purpose; many apps expect `.username` to be a thing, and you can just always assume `username == email`):

```
class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_artist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I also suggest looking into an app like [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) (which will work with custom user models) to make the whole register/login/password-change/email-confirmation flows easier.

Comment: Artist and Customer have some specific data in their tables and I need them what should I do then? How connect them to User(User table is Custom) and have a user that has both roles at a time?

Comment: You could have an extension model (CustomerData, ArtistData) with an OneToOneField to the User.

Comment: I have that Already but in that approach, an Artist can't be Customer

Comment: Of course they can. OneToOneFields just mean there can be only one User<->CustomerData pair and only one User<->ArtistData pair. It doesn't make those mutually exclusive.

Comment: I checked that because I have Email in User table I could not add an Artist and a Customer with equal Email.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my models a bit and create a OneToOne relation between Artist and Customer:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    Email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'Email'
    objects = MyUserManager()


class Customers(models.Model):
    User = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CustomerID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Artists(models.Model):
    Customer = models.OneToOneField(Customers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ArtistID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```